# apigee - Json payload extract variables

Tags: json, variables, extract, apigee

I am confused why the extractVariables rule I am using is returning data as it is.  See Below.

The json to Parse is:

```
{
    "callNotificationSubscriptionList": {
        "playAndCollectInteractionSubscription": [],
        "recognitionInteractionSubscription": [],
        "playAndRecordInteractionSubscription": [],
        "callDirectionSubscription": [],
        "callEventSubscription": [
            {
                "clientCorrelator": "112345",
                "resourceURL": "http:someurl",
                "callbackReference": {
                    "notifyURL": "someotherurlt",
                    "notificationFormat": "XML"
                },
                "filter": {
                    "data1": "data abc",
                    "data2": "data def",
                    "data3": "data xyz"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The rule:

```
<JSONPayload>
    <Variable name="callNotSubL">
        <!-- <JSONPath>$.callNotificationSubscriptionList</JSONPath> -->
        <JSONPath>$.*</JSONPath>
    </Variable>
</JSONpayload>
```

When I use the value that is commented out, I get no response variable data.  If I set the "ignoreUnresolvedVariables" parm to "false", I am returned a failure, so it has no data.  Thus, I tried "$.*"   With this, I am returned:

```
[
    {
        "callbackReference": {
            "notifyURL": "someotherurlt",
            "notificationFormat": "XML"
        },
        "filter": {
            "data1": "data abc",
            "data2": "data def",
            "data3": "data xyz"
        }
    }
]
```

could this be because the EntryNames are so long?  I admit they are long, but they are well under the default values in the JSON Threat Potection Policy.

I did pump this json though a web based JSONPayload parser and $.callNotificationSubscriptionList worked fine as did $.callNotificationSubscriptionList.callEventSubscription[0] which is what I am really after.  But, if I can't get the top level right, I can't get the sub-levels at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using [@Santanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808096/santanu-dey)'s comments:

> It seems that the JSON to parse getting through the policy is not same as what you are expecting? Can you try to assign entire payload to a variable using the AssignVariable policy before the JSON path extraction policy, and check the value of that variable in the debug view? That would help understand what payload value is actually passing through when you are trying to apply the json path extraction policy.

the `<Source>` tag was "request" and this was a response extract.  I removed the `<Source>` tag and all is well